# Repeating first anova in Titanic chapter from Regression Modeling Strategies course handout

Tags: r

I am trying to repeat case studies in "REGRESSION MODELING STRATEGIES" (http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/tmp/course.pdf) by Frank E Harrell Jr. But with R 3.2.3 and most current rms and Hmisc packages, for case study "Logistic Model Case Study: Survival of Titanic Passengers" in chapter 10, I cannot get Table 10.1 results. Instead, I have

```
Code:
require(rms)
titanic3 <- read.csv('../data/titanic3.csv', head = TRUE, sep = ',')
tn <- transform(titanic3,
            agec  = ifelse(age < 21, 'child', 'adult'),
            sibsp = ifelse(sibsp == 0, 'no sib/sp', 'sib/sp'),
            parch = ifelse(parch == 0, 'no par/child', 'par/child'),
            pclass = ordered(pclass, levels=c(1, 2, 3), labels=c('1st', '2nd', '3rd')))

f1 <- lrm(survived ~ sex * pclass * rcs(age, 5) + rcs(age, 5) * (sibsp + parch), data = titanic3)
anova(f1)


results:
           Wald Statistics          Response: survived 
 Factor                                            Chi-Square d.f. P     
 sex  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)                182.14     10   <.0001
   All Interactions                                  44.35      9   <.0001
 pclass  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)              77.55     10   <.0001
  All Interactions                                  29.59      9   0.0005
 age  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)                 53.38     24   0.0005
  All Interactions                                  34.33     20   0.0239
  Nonlinear (Factor+Higher Order Factors)           25.67     18   0.1074
 sibsp  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)               20.69      5   0.0009
  All Interactions                                  11.34      4   0.0230
 parch  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)                4.41      5   0.4917
  All Interactions                                   4.41      4   0.3531
 sex * pclass  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)        24.26      5   0.0002
 sex * age  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)           15.99      8   0.0426
  Nonlinear (Factor+Higher Order Factors)           13.01      6   0.0429
  Nonlinear Interaction : f(A,B) vs. AB              7.29      3   0.0633
 pclass * age  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)        10.57      8   0.2272
  Nonlinear (Factor+Higher Order Factors)            8.25      6   0.2201
  Nonlinear Interaction : f(A,B) vs. AB              2.97      3   0.3956
 age * sibsp  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)         11.34      4   0.0230
  Nonlinear                                          1.53      3   0.6752
  Nonlinear Interaction : f(A,B) vs. AB              1.53      3   0.6752
 age * parch  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)          4.41      4   0.3531
  Nonlinear                                          2.53      3   0.4700
  Nonlinear Interaction : f(A,B) vs. AB              2.53      3   0.4700
 sex * pclass * age  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)   6.46      4   0.1671
  Nonlinear                                          6.28      3   0.0989
 TOTAL NONLINEAR                                    25.67     18   0.1074
 TOTAL INTERACTION                                  59.68     21   <.0001
 TOTAL NONLINEAR + INTERACTION                      64.07     24   <.0001
 TOTAL                                             237.92     29   <.0001
Warning message:
In anova.rms(f1) :
  tests of nonlinear interaction with respect to single component 
variables ignore 3-way interactions
```

Can anyone help me find out what goes wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this explains it but you did not run the exact code given in that section of the handout.  Specifically it imports the dataset using

```
getHdata(titanic3)      # get dataset from web site
```

When I run the code using this and the latest `Hmisc` and `rms` updated on CRAN yesterday, I get identical results to what is in the handout.